# How to store custom nested objects in Room

Tags: android, kotlin, nested, android-room, android-architecture-components

I want to store this structure in Room database, the root Object is `ScheduleModel`. 
I got `error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database.` error after I tried to use @Entity and @PrivateKey.

Thanks.

```
data class ScheduleModel(
        val data: Data
)

data class Class(
        @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
        val name: String,
        val number: Int,
        val level: String,
        val schedule: List<Schedule>)

data class Data(
        @SerializedName("student") val classById: Class)

data class Lesson(
        val title: String,
        val icon: String)

data class Schedule(
        val index: String,
        val lesson: Lesson,
        val location: Any)
```

Comment: https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-room-relationships-bf473510c14a

Answer (score 0):

You have to save different type in different tables and use one-to-one or one-to-many interactions.
E.g.: in ScheduleModel room object you keep id of Data and get it from Data table. In Class room object you save list of Shedules’ ids, etc.